# Get indexOfObject from Associative Array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with finding the index of an array.
My Array Looks like that:

```
{"[NAME][NAME]", NSArray, NSArray}
```

I have to get the index of the object where a string equals to the first element of this associative array.

I have tried using a for loop, and counting an integer, but this does not work every time :/

EDIT:
This is the part i use to find the index out:

```
int tempIndex = -1, indexCount = 0;

for(NSArray *tempName in ABMembers){
    if([tempName[0] isEqualToString:memberName]){
        tempIndex = indexCount;
        break;
    } else {
        indexCount ++;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
**Sorry guys, I just found out what my problem was.. the arrays are dynamically generated, and the string that has to be compared to too, and the strings where not the same. that was the problem. so using any code here should work. sorry again**

Comment: what you have tried ? show something

Comment: If ABMembers array doesn't always contain an array at each index then this will crash - does it contain strings?

Comment: yes, it contains it everytime, it does not crash, thats not the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by {"[NAME][NAME]", NSArray, NSArray} ?????

Comment: What does *"but this does not work every time"* mean? Is "[NAME][NAME]" supposed to be an array of two elements?? Did you try to single-step in the debugger to find the problem?

Comment: it's just a string, the first element is a string, the second and third are nsarrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like following..

```
NSArray *arr1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];
NSArray *arr2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Three", @"Four", nil];

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"[NAME][NAME]",arr1, arr2, nil];

// A loop Through array
for(id Obj in arr)
{
    NSLog(@"Object %@ at %d",Obj,[arr indexOfObject:Obj]);
}
```

**OR if you know the Object**

```
// Direct index for object
NSLog(@"Index of Arr1 %d",[arr indexOfObject:arr1]);
NSLog(@"Index of String %d",[arr indexOfObject:@"[NAME][NAME]"]);
```

Comment: this is exactly the same as i had before, i know the object. but i don't know if 'NSLog(@"Index of String %d",[arr indexOfObject:@"[NAME][NAME]"]);' works, will try it later

Answer (score 0):

Change your arrays like this,

```
NSArray *array1 = @[@"Name 3",@"Name 4",@"Name 5",@"Name 6",@"Name 7"];
NSArray *array2 = @[@"Name 8",@"Name 9",@"Name 10",@"Name 11",@"Name 12"];


NSMutableArray *abMembers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[abMembers addObject:@"Name 1"];
[abMembers addObject:@"Name 2"];
[abMembers addObjectsFromArray:array1];
[abMembers addObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

Search for a name in the adMembers array,

```
NSString *nameToCheck = @"Name 5";
int foundIndex = -1;
for(NSString *s in abMembers){
    if([s isEqualToString:nameToCheck]){
       foundIndex = [abMembers indexOfObject:s];
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"found: %d", foundIndex);
```

Comment: 1. the first element is a string, and not an array
2. searching with this method, would crash the app

Comment: 1) If you don't know how to add the string name as the first element, I have changed the asnwer, 2) this code does not crash the app. copy paste and run

Comment: btw.. i don't want to add the object from the array into my array, i want to add the array itself to the array, so this is not what i wanted

Comment: you can, it then looks like that:

`{ 
    "[NAME][NAME]",
    { "TEXT1", "TEXT2" }, { "TEXT1", "TEXT2" }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I think this will help you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ABMembers count]; i++){
        if ([[ABMembers objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
            //compare the strings you want
        }
        else if ([[ABMembers objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            //you can do the the stuff with the arrays in your ABMembers array
        }
 }
```